# How to calculate the volume of a solid enclosed by surfaces?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am asked to calculate the volume of the solid enclosed by the following equations: (in polar coordinates)

r = Cos(θ)
z = 2 + x² + y²
z = 0

I know the second equation can be changed to its polar form:

z = 2 + r²

I also know the formula to calculate said volume is:

V = ∫∫ z(x,y) or V = ∫∫r dr dθ

However, I'm lost in terms of finding out the limits of integration and, therfore, the exact definite integral I need to calculate to obtain the volume. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think polar coordinates apply to your situation; perhaps you mean cylindrical coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[
   (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= Cos[ArcTan[x, y]]), {x, y}];

Plot3D[2 + x^2 + y^2, Element[{x, y}, rgn],
 Filling -> 0,
 PlotRange -> {0, 3},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"x", "y", "z"})]
```

[image]

The volume between z==0 and z==2 + x^2 + y^2 is

```
Integrate[2 + x^2 + y^2, Element[{x, y}, rgn]]

(*  (19*Pi)/32  *)
```

Alternatively,

```
rgn3D = ImplicitRegion[
   (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= Cos[ArcTan[x, y]]) &&
    (0 <= z <= 
      2 + x^2 + y^2), {x, y, z}];

Volume[rgn3D]

(*  (19*Pi)/32  *)
```

However, `RegionPlot3D[rgn3D]` displays the wrong volume!

```
RegionPlot3D[rgn3D,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"x", "y", "z"})]
```

[image]

Although the default option is `PlotRange->Full`, explicitly specifying the `PlotRange` is needed.

```
RegionPlot3D[rgn3D, PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}), 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}, {0, 3}},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: somehow i doubt that helps with his calculus homework :)

Comment: @george2079 - I'm more concerned as to why `RegionPlot3D` failed.

Comment: does an explicit plotrange help?

Comment: @george2079 - that worked; but I could not just specify the the plot range for z but had to add the full `PlotRange` specification.

Comment: If you simplify to `x^2+y^2<=x` then `RegionPlot` works.